# Get the optimal path from A*

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, a-star

I started creating the A* algorithm. The player should walk from bottom left to top right. There are different field cost per cell. Having costs of 0 means the cell is not walkable.

Sometimes the player jumps around because in my closed list I don't have the optimal path, some "wrong" cells are in there too.

You can have a look here

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/370618181892571136/446345906464358410/zgzugzzu.gif

I have a `map` object that creates the map and holds all `cell` objects in a 2D array of type `cell`. Each cell knows its own field cost but they don't need to know their position because the array knows it by passing in the x and y value.

Some explanations say that I have to store the **predecessor** of the current examined node and compare the current value of costs when using this path to other paths.

How can I do this?

My current code

```
private List < Vector2Int > openCells = new List < Vector2Int > ();
private List < Vector2Int > closedCells = new List < Vector2Int > ();

private void CalculatePath() {
 openCells.Clear();
 closedCells.Clear();

 openCells.Add(Settings.startPosition);

 Vector2Int currentCellPosition = Settings.startPosition;

 while (!PositionEquals(currentCellPosition, Settings.targetPosition) && openCells.Count > 0) {
  Vector2Int cheapestCellPosition = openCells
   .OrderBy(x => GetCostToTarget(x, Settings.targetPosition) + GetCell(x).Cost)
   .First();

  AddNeighbourPosition(cheapestCellPosition, Vector2Int.up);
  AddNeighbourPosition(cheapestCellPosition, Vector2Int.left);
  AddNeighbourPosition(cheapestCellPosition, Vector2Int.down);
  AddNeighbourPosition(cheapestCellPosition, Vector2Int.right);

  closedCells.Add(cheapestCellPosition);
  openCells.Remove(cheapestCellPosition);

  currentCellPosition = cheapestCellPosition;
 }
}

private void AddNeighbourPosition(Vector2Int currentPosition, Vector2Int neighbourDirection) {
 Vector2Int targetPosition = currentPosition + neighbourDirection;

 if (CellExistsOnMap(targetPosition)) {
  if (CellIsWalkable(targetPosition)) {
   if (!CellExamined(targetPosition)) {
    openCells.Add(targetPosition);
   }
  }
 }
}

private bool PositionEquals(Vector2Int startPosition, Vector2Int targetPosition) {
 return startPosition.Equals(targetPosition);
}

private bool CellIsWalkable(Vector2Int position) {
 return GetCell(position).Cost != 0;
}

private Cell GetCell(Vector2Int position) {
 return map.Cells[position.x, position.y];
}

private int GetCostToTarget(Vector2Int startPosition, Vector2Int targetPosition) {
 return Mathf.Abs(startPosition.x - targetPosition.x) + Mathf.Abs(startPosition.y - targetPosition.y);
}

private bool CellExistsOnMap(Vector2Int position) {
 int horizontalLength = Settings.fields.GetLength(0);
 int verticalLength = Settings.fields.GetLength(1);
 Rect mapRect = new Rect(0, 0, horizontalLength, verticalLength);

 return mapRect.Contains(position);
}

private bool CellExamined(Vector2Int position) {
 return openCells.Contains(position) || closedCells.Contains(position);
}
```

Comment: Your code does not appear to actually implement `A*`.  If you want a tutorial on how to implement `A*` in C#, consider this series of articles from my blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/astar/

Answer (score 2):

First you haven't implemented A* correctly and missed some points,

1. There's no function in your code calculating so far path distance
   (G)
2. You add neighbors to openlist only if it doesn't contain them
   already, which is wrong and you have to compare current cell total
   cost and compare it with the old one in the openlist, and if the
   cost is less you have to update cell cost in the list...

For holding a reference to predecessor of current cell, you need to change your cell data structure , it's recommend to be a struct for avoiding GC allocations, but a struct can not have a field with the same type struct to store the predecessor since it create a loop.
If your map size is small and the pathfinding process is not called per cell advance , implementing it using a class is all fine.

```
public class Cell
{
public Vector2Int Position { get;set;}
public int Cost {get;set;}
public Cell Parent {get;set;}
}
```

Another option is to use LinkedList for your closedlist to track back from target cell to current one.

You haven't shared the code how you find the path from closedlist when your calculations are over, I believe the jumping issue comes from there